# tomcat server not starting while port is open

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I was ran my tomcat9 server using debugger mode and got below errors

```
'#export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#CATALINA_HOME' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#CATALINA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'LOGGING_MANAGER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'LOGGING_CONFIG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat-9"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat-9"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Tomcat-9\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Tomcat-        
9\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat-9\lib\log4j-jul-        
2.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat-9\lib\log4j-core-2.6.2.jar;C:\Program     
Files\Tomcat-9\lib\log4j-api-2.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat- 
9\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

my java version is 11 and I set up path correctly and it is ok,and I also tried using different port number for start tomcat9 server using "catalina.bat jpda start" command but I got above error and what is the reason for that?

Comment: You seem to somehow be running the unix version of the catalina script on windows.

Comment: does it work without debug flag? is there another tomcat running?